# How to make stylus to include content of imported CSS instead of generating CSS import statement?

Tags: stylus

The `@import "reset.css"` in Stylus `.styl`file would generate `@import "reset.css"` entry in CSS.

Is there a way to make Stylus to instead include the content of the included CSS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can specify this in the options param of the `stylus.render` function, like

```
stylus.render(inputString, {'include css': true}, cb)
```